# Imported certificate (via keytool) not displaying in Java Control Panel

Tags: java, certificate-store

I imported a root signer CA certificate into Java SE 8 using the following command:

```
keytool -importcert -alias "DigiCert Global Root G2" -file DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
```

I got the following message that the certificate was imported successfully:  "Certificate was added to keystore".  I know that it was added, because I can view information for it using the keytool -list command.

However, when I view the Java Control Panel and go into Manage Certificates, the certificate doesn't appear anywhere.  I rebooted my PC after importing the certificate.  I looked everywhere in Manage Certificates:  in both the User and System tabs for every certificate type.

Does anyone have any idea why the imported certificate isn't showing up in the control panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your command and see if that works:

```
-keystore $JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts
```

Note: in case your JAVA_HOME is set to jdk, the path will be :

```
-keystore $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

The default password of keystore is "changeit". Also be careful about the white space in your "JAVA_HOME" variable.

Comment: That took care of it.  When I did my initial import, keytool created a new keystore named .keystore in my Windows home directory.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.